# LM7805 gets very hot with four servo motors

Tags: arduino-uno, esp32, servo, robotics

I'm making a robotic arm using three SG90s and one Futaba s3003 servo motors and an ESP32 dev_kit_V4.

The problem is when I am controlling the arm, the voltage regulator gets so hot that I can't touch it. After a minute or so the servos stop rotating and I have to restart the ESP32 to control the servos and the cylce continues.

I tried to connect the ESP32 to a power bank alone but the issue isn't solved. Can you help me?

The schematic for wiring:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Depending on load, your servos can draw 250ma of current or more when actuated. This means that your 7805 may need to supply >1 amp of current at 5V.

In order to get 5V from a 12V adapter the 7805 will need to drop 7V (The LM7805 is a linear regulator, essentially a variable resistor). 7V at 1 amp (peak) is 7 watts, which is what your regulator will dissipate during peak current draw.

With effective heat sinking your circuit will work. According to the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm340.pdf), if you are running at room temperature with no heat sink you are limited to ~2.5 watts of dissipation.

If the 7805 chip temperature exceeds 150 degrees C it will go into thermal shutdown, which is probably what you're seeing.

Solutions would be to install an appropriate heat sink on the 7805, use a 7.5 volt power adapter (brings 7805 power dissipation down to ~2.5 watts), use multiple 7805 chips, or power everything with a 5V power adapter.

Comment: thanks , I will add a heatsink and see if it fixes the problem

Comment: I've added a heatsink and it works , thank you

Answer (score 1):

Linear regulators especially the older ones like to go into oscillation at a relative high frequency. This may be load dependent.  The data sheet will recommend the appropriate capacitors to connect to it to prevent that. You would typically use a scope to see this. That oscillation will cause them to get hot rapidly even if they do not have a large load. You can look at the data sheet and determine the temperature rise of the die per watt of power. That you can determine by multiplying the drop across the regulator by the current. You can also apply this to heatsinks and pick one accordingly. There are conditions on this to be sure you have adequate ventilation to get rid of the heat on a air cooled heatsink. Liquid are similar but the numbers are much different.

In your case I would recommend you go to a switch mode regulator, commonly known as a buck or SEPIC regulator. The buck will drop the voltage from a higher voltage. The SEPIC does the same thing but if the input voltage goes below the output setpoint within its range it will boost the voltage keeping it at setpoint. As BobT explained the excess voltage is dropped through the regulator, it sort of acts like a variable resistor. This is dissipated as heat. The current on the input is about the same as the output. A switch mode regulator will operate in the efficiency range of maybe 80% - 95% efficiency, dissipating much less heat. They actually turn on and off very rapidly but the output is filtered so you do not see it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to go with lm2596. That will solve your problem. Its output is adjustable. So set the output voltage first before connecting anything to it.

Comment: thanks for your reply,but I can't get it now because there is no electrical stores near to me